# Author, Paper I, II, III, and IV

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, biber

Is there a good practice to create one citation to a few papers of one author with identical title published in the same journal.

> John, Gee. Title I, II, II, and IV, *Journal of Anatarctida,* 7 (1885), 234--321; 8 (1886), 1234--1321; 9 (1887), 3234--3321; 11 (1889), 7234--7321.

Is there a trick to create something like this using biber/bibtex?

Comment: I have no idea how to implement this in Latex, but maybe a comment on good scientific practice: Personally, I would never do this. Even if journal and title are the same, the content will be different. When you use a reference it should be specific to a statement in the text. If this is true for several references, cite all of them seperately. Also think of the other way around: You want to cite only one of the references. Then you would need another entry in bibliography which is somehow redundant.